# Can twitter4j search provide 2 dates?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

i am using twitter4j to search tweets. I saw someone said it can search tweets between 2 dates and it can return more than 100 tweets (by default it is max 100 tweets). But after I tried, it didn't work. I can only retrieve 100 tweets from Mon Jul 01 14:55:36 to Jul 01 23:47:50. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

```
 Query query = new Query("haze")
 query.setSince("2013-06-30");
 query.setUntil("2013-07-02");
 query.geoCode(new GeoLocation(XXX, XXX), 200, Query.KILOMETERS);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, you are limited to a maximum of 100 Tweets but what you could do is set [`Query#sinceId(long)`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Query.html#sinceId%28long%29) with the `Id` of last `Status` received allowing you to effectively step through the results, e.g.:

```
final QueryResult result = twitter.search(query); // 100 Tweets

final Status lastStatus = getLast(result.getTweets());

query.sinceId(lastStatus.getId());
final QueryResult nextResult = twitter.search(query); // Another 100 Tweets

// and so on...
```

You could easily put the above in loop but be careful that you don't hit any rate limits. Also, be aware you cannot [search for Tweets older than about a week using the search api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search).